# Device is a Printer

Tags: android, linux, windows, printing, driver

I want to connect an android device to regular electronic cash register (linux and windows base) to collect the receipt data from it. Beside the regular option of working with the  APIs of each type of electronic cash register out there and doing a data transfer, we are considering an option of installing Android Device as a Printer on the cash register.

**Is it possible to develop a Printer driver that will be installed in a linux and windows based cash registers which will make the cash register see Android Phone as a printer?** Thus we will be able to send the receipt for print from the cash register and it will arrive at the Android phone?

thanks

Comment: *Is it possible to develop a Printer driver that will be installed in a linux and windows based cash registers which will make the cash register see Android Phone as a printer?* Maybe. I've **never** seen it done, but that doesn't make it *impossible*. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I would not (on Linux) code a driver for the kernel, but simply customize or extend the CUPS printing system.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I have asked the developer who is developing the application but his team has not done this before and they were not sure if it can be done. Hence I queried here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Will check with the development team if they have the know how of working with CUPS. It would be really neat if we can get the data from the cash register to the phone and than able to read the file, extract the information we need and apply our analytics